# Should MPI be built with the same compiler suite as the application

Tags: parallel-processing, compilation, mpi

I am working on an MPI application for scientific computing. I am working on our distribution process, and it raise the question of the version of the MPI.

I read at some places on the net that MPI should be built with the same compiler suite as the application, but nothing really explaining why.

So I wonder what defines a version of MPI, once it has been compiled? Is it just the version of the source package, or is it the version of the source package plus the compiler suite and its version that has been used to compile MPI?

Comment: If you use Fortran modules (e.g. `use mpi` or `use mpi_f08`) then it is a no-brainer. Fortran modules are not interoperable, so the same compiler (both vendor and version) must used to build MPI and the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the MPI implantation is an absolute must. A typical example being an type having changed between versions.

You should also compile all involved libraries - particularly MPI - with the same compiler version. A typical example are compiler-specific libraries. One compiler replaces a call to `memcpy` with a built-in optimized version. If you try to link with a different compiler, that doesn't provide that optimized function in it's library, you get a linker error. System libraries are usually fine, but for highly optimized builds as well as C++ codes, these kinds of library ABI (application binary interface) incompatibilities are common and very painful.